Response code 403 (Forbidden) when trying to create an Snapchat media using the api
I am trying to create an Snapchat media like shown here: https://marketingapi.snapchat.com/docs/profile.html#create-media
but unfortunaly i am getting the response code 403.
i exchange the token with these scopes: "snapchat-marketing-api, snapchat-offline-conversions-api, snapchat-profile-api" (i tested it with "https://businessapi.snapchat.com/v1/organizations/.../public_profiles?limit=1" and it worked fine)
this is my curl command:
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ..." -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"...","type":"VIDEO","iv":"AXSfK3PYiHJvytFim5NkyA==","key":"BmeJyouYpcWZgIAdeqK7f95AkNXWU8F2sg5Y+PH/1I4="}' https://businessapi.snapchat.com/v1/public_profiles/3aabb0c8-6c48-4b23-826e-712ef683f574/media
or
curl --request POST 'https://businessapi.snapchat.com/v1/public_profiles/3aabb0c8-6c48-4b23-826e-712ef683f574/media' --header 'Authorization: Bearer ...' --data-raw "{\"name\":\"...\",\"type\":\"VIDEO\",\"iv\":\"KMltGAVeCWk7KW+uhF1jZQ==\",\"key\":\"FBtknLkc8yml6PgvFo4fSHVZh2aakMLx1NyDEcIWxEs=\"}"

Expected would be an response like this:
{
    "request_id": "ecfe244d-0b1b-4787-9919-4ee7dd275a0a",
    "request_status": "SUCCESS",
    "media_id": "abed133c-0b1b-3676-8808-3dd6cc164909", 
    "add_path": "/us/v1/public_profiles/62d2298b-925b-4953-9cb0-b3a492d51d0c/media/abed133c-0b1b-3676-8808-3dd6cc164909/multipart-upload",
    "finalize_path": "/us/v1/public_profiles/62d2298b-925b-4953-9cb0-b3a492d51d0c/media/abed133c-0b1b-3676-8808-3dd6cc164909/multipart-upload"
}


Hi, i am encountering the same problem, have you found a solution by any chance?

Has Snapchat dev team granted you access to the api like stated in the doc here : https://marketingapi.snapchat.com/docs/profile.html#introduction ?

Im pretty sure they never send an response

How did you get in touch with them if i may ask?

i mean i tried sending an email to dev-support@snap.com like said in the introduction but never managed to get in touch with them

OK thanks for your answers Finn. Did the same 3 days ago i guess it is no more worth waiting.

Yea their api is really bad i wasted an bunch of time on it and got nowhere
